# Toggle images in Firefox on a per-tab basis?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there any way in Firefox to enable/disable loading of images (and ideally also scripts) per tab, and have links opened in new tabs inherit the setting?

It seems like it should be simple, but all I found was a plugin that toggles images globally, and another that's per tab, but still has a global setting for whether links opened in new tabs have images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution of creating a new Firefox profile (`firefox --ProfileManager`), launching it with `firefox --no-remote -P my-alternate-profile-name`, and installing a global image toggle plugin in it. This basically creates a per-window image setting, for the window running with that profile instead of the default one. In some ways it might even be better than a per-tab setting since it also allows other browser configurations to be changed independently, but it's also really inconvenient that the bookmarks and history are not shared, so I'll still wait for more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I've re-read your question and realised that I misunderstood. A tool like Adblock might be the better option as it applies the blocks on a per domain basis, this would allow your new tabs to follow the same restrictions.

It is also easy to disable temporarily as required.

---

This used to be a standard option in the right-click menu until recent versions. Mozilla decided to move it to prevent accidental activation.

The steps to disable images now are as follows:

1. Enter `about:config` in the URL bar.
2. Accept the warning about invalidating your warranty.
3. Enter `permissions.default.image` into the search box on the configuration page.
4. Double click on the top option.
5. Change the value from `1` to `2` to the pop up.

   - `1` - loads images automatically (the default)
   - `2` - disables loading images automatically

([source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976872))

You can now restart your browser to allow the new settings to take effect.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what Adblock can do, the question was about toggling images per tab (or at least per window), not globally or per domain.